# Thymeleaf could not parse as expression

Tags: java, spring-mvc

For my work I have to work with Spring and Thymeleaf.

The following line returns error: Could not parse as expression:

```
 <script th:src='${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you can solve it in two ways:

1. Using [text literals](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#text-literals)

`<script th:src="|${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js|"></script>`

2. Using [link urls](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

`<script th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js}"></script>`